# Copying an element using .html() and then putting it to another <div>, is it safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it a good idea to copy a div using jQuery's .html() function and then put it in another division.

It's like I've made a hidden element which has divisions with specific ids (eg: login form in a div identified by **#login**, and in another the registration form identified by **#reg**)

now by clicking on the login button in the nav menu, I'm copying the div using **$("#login").html()** in a javascript variable which has the id **#login** in that hidden variable set. and then putting it to the main viewport (which is a <div>) with some fadeIn and fadeOut effects.

So my question is, is it ok to do like this? or it has some negetive effects?

```
<a href="#l2">Login</a>  <!-- a button in nav bar -->

<div class="plate"></div> <!-- view port -->



           <div class="hidden data"> <!-- set of hidden divs -->
                <div id="l1">   <!-- ///////////////////////// -->

                    Default

                </div>
                <div id="l2">   <!-- ///////////////////////// -->

                    <div id="form-box">
                        <form method="post" action="#">

                            <input class="fancy" style="background:url(img/user.png) no-repeat 20px center;" name="user" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" placeholder="Email..."><br/>
                            <input style="background:url(img/key.png) no-repeat 20px center;" name="pass" autocomplete="off" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br/><br/>
                            <button type="submit">GO</button>

                        </form>
                        <a class="forgot-pass btn">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="l4">   <!-- ///////////////////////// -->

                    Default

                </div>
                <div id="l3">   <!-- ///////////////////////// -->

                    <div id="form-box">
                        <form method="post" action="#">

                            <input name="user" style="background:url(img/user.png) no-repeat 20px center;" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" placeholder="Username..."><br/>
                            <input name="email" style="background:url(img/email-48.png) no-repeat 20px center;" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" placeholder="Email..."><br/>
                            <input name="pass" style="background:url(img/key.png) no-repeat 20px center;" autocomplete="off" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br/>
                            <input name="pass_again" style="background:url(img/key.png) no-repeat 20px center;" autocomplete="off" type="password" placeholder="Password Again..."><br/><br/>
                            <button type="submit">GO</button>

                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>





    <script type="text/javascript">
        var screenH = $(window).height();
        var navH = $(".nav").height();
        var folioH = screenH - navH;
        $("#folio").css("height",folioH+"px");

        $(".menu a").on("click",function(){
            var data = $(this).attr("href");
            var target = $(this).attr("data-target");

            var data = $(data).html();
            $(target).fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).html(data).fadeIn(500);
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but possibly due to poor formatting, and also it's not quite clear what you're asking. Also people tend to downvote more if you post comments like "why the downvote?" (most people don't comment even after asking).

Comment: If you could show us a demo by example or something, we could easily help narrow the question down because i know i barely understand it.

Comment: I'm not seeing what benefit you're getting by duplicating the contents of one node into another, rather than simply repositioning or revealing the original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is since you'll have duplicate ids that way.

Use the following code to move the element in the DOM:

```
jQuery("#login").hide().appendTo("#viewport").fadeIn();
```